# Change value on dynamic input fields in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the input value on dynamically added input fields.

Each input field value is set to a state value which is made of an array.

Seems like there should be a simple solution for this.. But I can't just figure it out.

JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o51Lkvm6/1/

```
handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}

    render()  {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.data.map((d, index) =>
                    <input name={d.Name} type="text" className="form-control" 
                  value={d.Name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                 )}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Update:
Is it possible to solve this without having to use defaultvalue? Since React does not recommend "Uncontrolled Components"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are couple issues with your code:

- You forgot to bind your handler method or use arrow function to
  preserve this context of a class. To fix that you can either put this
  in Test constructor:

```
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
```

or modify your existing function to:

```
  handleInputChange = e => {};
```

- Input value should actually use the value which
  corresponds to current item from state, like that:

```
value={this.state.data[index]["Name"]}
```

- Later to access proper item in your stateData you have to somehow
  store that index in the input. I did this by assigning it to
  data-index attribute. Also you forgot to include key prop:

```
 <input
   key={d.ID}
   data-index={index}
   name={d.Name}
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   value={this.state.data[index]["Name"]}
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  />
```

- In your actual handleInputChange you were not targeting the correct
  thing. You need to first get the appropriate item from the array and
  then modify the name. I did it by copying the actual state and later
  assigning it:

```
  handleInputChange = e => {
    const stateDataCopy = this.state.data.slice();
    const objectCopy = Object.assign({}, stateDataCopy[e.target.dataset.index]);
    objectCopy["Name"] = e.target.value;
    stateDataCopy[e.target.dataset.index] = objectCopy;
    this.setState({ data: stateDataCopy });
  };
```

- Here you can find working example:

[image: Edit cranky-maxwell-ob3tl]

Comment: This is more what I was looking for! Thanks alot!

Comment: @arkhz no worries, it was really good question, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

ok I fixed it for you

do these 2 things

`handleInputChange(e){` make this an arrow function so it has the concept of `this` like so: `handleInputChange = (e) => {`

and use `defaultValue` instead of `value` in the input

updated fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/a17gywvp/1/

Comment: Thank you for the responses. This does solve my problem - but is it the best solution since it's a "uncontrolled component"? 

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:~:text=In%20the%20React%20rendering%20lifecycle,defaultValue%20attribute%20instead%20of%20value%20.